# How to insert multiple rows in one column using one INSERT statement in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I'm trying this query, but it's not working

```
insert into REGIONS(region_name) values ('SOUTH_AFRICA') , ('NORTH_AFRICA');
```

Comment: it should be  as below
insert into REGIONS(region_name) values ('SOUTH_AFRICA');
insert into REGIONS(region_name) values ('NORTH_AFRICA');

Comment: I know that but I'm required to use only one INSERT statment

Comment: Weird that Oracle doesn't support this syntax.

Comment: @JacobH unfortunately 11g doesn't support it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO` with `SELECT` as below:

```
INSERT INTO REGIONS (region_name) 
SELECT 'SOUTH_AFRICA' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'NORTH_AFRICA' FROM DUAL
```

Comment: " ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected "

Comment: I got this error message

Comment: it's not working , "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Comment: @ToqaYousri Can you try to updated answer

Comment: i got this " cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."REGIONS"."REGION_ID")"

Comment: Seems you have a not null column named `REGION_ID`, so it is not allowing insert. You can include the column in the `insert into` and add the value for the same in the `select`

Comment: like that !?
"insert into regions(region_id,region_name) select (1,'south_africa') from dual union select (2,'north_africa') from dual"

Comment: @ToqaYousri Yes, like that. But no need of paraenthesis for SELECT

Comment: " unique constraint (HR.REG_ID_PK) violated"

Comment: @ToqaYousri just remove parentheses within the select statements.

Comment: @ToqaYousri It means, `REGION_ID` value should be unique, it can't be repeat. You are trying to insert a duplicate value in the `REGION_ID` column

Comment: i can't get the solution ):